# Objective C: Syntax when doing arithmetic in messaging

Tags: objective-c

I am learning Obj-C and having trouble understanding this syntax the first line works but the second, where I perform arithmetic on the integer `length` (-1) it complains. why is this?

```
self.historyDisplay.text = [self.historyDisplay.text 
          substringToIndex:[self.historyDisplay.text length]];

self.historyDisplay.text = [self.historyDisplay.text 
          substringToIndex:[self.historyDisplay.text length-1]];
```

Comment: @JoshCaswell, it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

`length` is not an integer, it's the name of a message that *returns* an integer.  You want to do math on that result, so you need the `-1` to be outside the message (`text` variable used here to shorten up the line):

```
text = self.historyDisplay.text;
self.historyDisplay.text = [text substringToIndex:[text length] - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[target selector]` syntax encapsulates a message dispatch. Do your math on the result of it—outside the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

`length` is the name of the message that returns the length, so

```
[self.historyDisplay.text length-1]
```

is a syntax error, it should be

```
[self.historyDisplay.text length] - 1
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.historyDisplay.text = [self.historyDisplay.text substringToIndex:[self.historyDisplay.text length]-1];
```